# How to provide local image urls from Rails 5 API only app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

We have an API only, Rails 5 app (so no pipeline). We want the API to provide a URL to an image on our server. This image is provided by a Model. This image could live in `app/assets/images` or `public/images`. What method will append the current host/domain to a filename, in a Rails Model?

We expected `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("solar.png")` to work, but this returns `"\solar.png"`.

We have set default_url_options to "localhost:3000"

It would be acceptable to have the model provide just the filename and the controller/json view renderer provides the URL portion via a helper.  I say "acceptable", because our model is deciding what image should be returned. Sometimes that image is from the local server, sometimes it is an absolute URL from a different server. If the controller provides the URL portion, we would have to handle these two cases separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast answer:

```
# development.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
# production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://yourdomain.com"
```

The common mistake is to set `config.action_controller.default_url_options`

Remember you have severals places to set your hostname:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options
config.action_mailer.default_url_options
config.action_controller.asset_host
# Maybe others, I'm not sure
```

It's often the same value, but not everytimes.